# Table data showing

Tags: android

I am building one app which is a copy of a website.
In that website they showed some bulk of data in a table view (with multiple rows and columns)
I want to show the same bulk of data in android mobile.

But the problem is which widget will be reliable to show large amount of data (like table). And which widget will give efficient and professional look.

Please suggest some widget or views

Answer (score 0):

- For a static (predefined/known)
  content you can use `TableLayout`,
  [as in this example](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tablelayout.html),
- For dynamically populate the table
  you should use a [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html)
  (considering as an option the
  [`ListView`](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) as well: if you don't
  have many columns, an proper item
  renderer would be more efficient).